# Best way to strip everything except numbers and decimal points from a string in Python

Tags: python, filter

I’m reading an ASCII data stream with Python 2.7 that includes non-negative numbers with decimal places but also “garbage characters” that include nonprintables, letters, and punctuation.  I can strip out the non-printables this way:

```
rawdata2 = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, rawdata)
```

but that leaves a string like such:

Ri-G2015,2,20.23,9.13,273.1- ZW;w;K-;-A;B`R

What’s a good way to strip out everything except numbers and decimal points (.) so I’m left with this:

2015,2,20.23,9.13,273.1

Comment: Do you want to keep commas?

Comment: Yes, you are right - I do need to keep commas.

Answer (score 4):

A faster approach is to use regular expressions:

```
import re

rawdata2 = re.sub('[^0-9,.]', '', rawdata)
```

This simply deletes any characters not in the set `0-9 , .` (by replacing them with an empty string). This is over twice as fast as the filter approach on 100 repetitions of your input string, and is more concise.

---

The fastest approach (if you're processing a lot of text) is to use `string.translate`:

```
deltable = "".join(chr(c) for c in xrange(256) if chr(c) not in "0123456789,.")

rawdata2 = string.translate(rawdata, None, deltable)
```

This is over 100x faster than your original filter approach.

Comment: Faster than what? Using `in`? Why don't you try it first before making that kind of claim.

Comment: @nanny: added profiling information, and the fastest approach `string.translate`.

Comment: I just profiled your `re` version versus my `filter` answer, and mine is over 20 times faster (1000 repetitions, python 3.4.3). I don't know how you're getting "This is over twice as fast as the filter approach"

Comment: @nanny: On Python 3.4, `filter` is lazy and returns only an iterator. Try `''.join(filter(...))`.

Answer (score 3):

`string.printable` is just a string. You can use your own string in its place, like:

```
rawdata2 = filter(lambda x: x in ',.0123456789', rawdata)
```

Note that I included a comma, because your expected output also includes commas.

Answer (score 1):

```
keepchars = string.digits + ",." #the characters you want to keep
rawdata2 = filter(lambda x: x in keepchars, rawdata)
```

I'd go with this since it seems like you want to whitelist chars. If instead you decide you want to blacklist chars, [string.translate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) might be a good place to look.

Answer (score 0):

I love regular expressions. It's elegant,Since i don't know re...

```
In [45]: "".join([i for i in mystring if i=="." or i.isdigit() or i==','])
Out[45]: '2015,2,20.23,9.13,273.1'
```

Comment: But... you're not *using* regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  My program doesn't need to be speedy since it's processing just one line every few minutes, but I appreciate learning about the efficiency of the different approaches.  I ended up using the following two lines:

```
include = set('0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '.' ',')
```

and then

```
cleandata1 = ''.join(ch for ch in rawdata if ch in include)
```

Later I inserted a third line to save the garbage characters for inspection:

```
garbage = ''.join(ch for ch in rawdata if ch not in include)
```